# Not getting value from property inside AttributeConverter

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, converters

I have created a converter and want to get `secretKey` from the property file.

```
@Converter
public class CryptoConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {

    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";
    private byte[] secretKey;

    public CryptoConverter(@Value("${access_token_encryption_key}") String encryptionKey) {
        secretKey = encryptionKey.getBytes();
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String ccNumber) {
        // do some encryption
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey, "AES");
        try {
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            return Base64.encodeBytes(c.doFinal(ccNumber.getBytes()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        // do some decryption
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey, "AES");
        try {
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            return new String(c.doFinal(Base64.decode(dbData)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I have added `access_token_encryption_key` key in application.properties file but not able to get value for the key `access_token_encryption_key`.

I think this convertor loading before spring beans. Is there any idea of how this can be solved?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution with @Component annotation and @Autowired setter method and assigned value to the static variable.

```
private static byte[] accessTokenEncryptionKey;

    @Autowired
    public void setAccessTokenEncryptionKey(
            @Value("${tokyo_channel.access_token_encryption_key}") String accessTokenEncryptionKey) {
        CryptoConverter.accessTokenEncryptionKey = accessTokenEncryptionKey.getBytes(ISO_8859_1);
    }
```

Now I am able to get value from the property file.

Answer (score 1):

The converter is not managed by Spring.

Add the @Component annotation to make it a Spring Bean:

```
@Component
@Converter
public class CryptoConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but still not able to get value from the property key.